# How to change the direction of gravity in Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to build a game about billiards. The screen is like a table, the default direction of the gravity system is downward, that is, the Y axis. And I want to change this direction to Z axis, so the ball has both gravity effect and will not fall down. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: `physicsWorld.gravity` in spritekit is a 2D vector (dx,dy) and thus has no concept of the z axis. for a top-down billiard game you might try turning gravity off `self.physicsWorld.gravity = .zero` and then use `velocity` and `linearDamping` on your ball nodes to simulate realistic rolling

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, I would use friction to achieve your desired effect. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519840-friction

Comment: @Fault Do you mean to use linearDamping to simulate friction due to gravity. I got it, thank you.

Comment: i'll repost my comment as answer ;)

Comment: Please don't edit your question title to add things like "RESOLVED". If you managed to solve your question, please **accept** the answer that helped your most (by ticking the checkmark), or if there are no answers or no existing answer was helpful, post your own answer and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`physicsWorld.gravity` in SpriteKit is a 2D vector (dx,dy) and thus has no concept of the z axis.

for a top-down billiard game you might try turning gravity off `self.physicsWorld.gravity = .zero` and then use `velocity` and `linearDamping` on your billiard ball nodes to simulate realistic rolling.